# Google Apps Script Library removes itself from standalone projects

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, clasp

I've published a standalone Google Apps Script project, and I include this code in 4 different scripts bound to 4 sheets. I develop locally using Clasp in combination with TypeScript, according to [this](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/typescript.md) setup.

The problem I experience is that sometimes when I push edits through Clasp my code in those standalone scripts (I never edit my library code) seems to remove the included library. Obviously, my code in the standalone scripts then fails to execute. I then have to manually re-add the library in all 4 bound scripts.

Development mode is turned off in all scripts.

Comment: I may have found my answer here: one can [include libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests) in the `appsscript.json` file. I'm guessing adding the library there will solve my problem.

Comment: Are you pulling before pushing? If not... why not?

Answer (score 2):

One can [include libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests) in the appsscript.json file. This way, the library is properly attached to the code.

Comment: After a couple of days, the issue returned. This alone will not help.